# ClickableSpan TextView stays selected after click

Tags: android

I'm using the following code to make my `TextView` appear like a link, and when user clicks on it I show an `AlertDialog`.  But the text stays selected after user leaves the dialog and it looks ugly.

```
    TextView terms = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewTerms);
    terms.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    Spannable spanTerms = (Spannable)terms.getText();
    ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View view)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutActivity.this)
                .setTitle(R.string.title_terms)
                .setMessage(R.string.terms_of_use)
                .setCancelable(true)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .show();
        }
    };

    spanTerms.setSpan(clickSpan, 0, spanTerms.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

I've also tried calling `setSelected(false)` but that doesn't work either.  Any ideas?

Comment: What do you exactly want after clicking ok in dialog?

Comment: Nothing, I just don't want the text to be selected.

Comment: Try setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT). This will work. Although, if you use this clicking on your clickable text will not yield any highlight at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `Selection.setSelection(spanTerms, 0);` inside your `onClick` method of your dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a custom TextView.
Basically, enable highlighting only if the view is in the pressed state.

```
@Override
public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
    if (pressed) {
        setHighlightColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.highlight_color));
    } else {
        setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
    super.setPressed(pressed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text to be clicked only once then you can do it like this.
Add a Boolean variable `isClickedOnce` initialize it with `false`,then before `AlertDialog.Builder` check if it is `false` like below code :

```
ClickableSpan clickSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {
                    if (!isClickedOnce) {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(AboutActivity.this)
                            .setTitle("title_terms")
                            .setMessage("terms_of_use")
                            .setCancelable(true)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(
                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int which) {
                                            isClickedOnce = true;
                                             Log.i("isClickedOnce","isClickedOnce"+isClickedOnce);
                                            dialog.dismiss();


                                        }
                                    }).show();
                    }


                }

            };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
textView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```