# How to make an Android TextView TextColor stay highlighted?

Tags: android

I have a TextView in a ListView.I want the TextColor of the TextView stay highlighted when selected.It's working fine in newer versions, but in lower versions it's not being highlighted, it's just blinking.

Here is my xml:

listview_bell_items.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:padding="5dip" >

       <TextView
             android:id="@+id/txt_bell_title"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:text="@string/rihanna_love_the_way_lie"
             android:textColor="@drawable/bell_selected_text_color"
             android:textSize="15sp"
             android:textStyle="bold"
             android:typeface="sans" />

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_bell_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/bronze_bell" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

bell_selected_text_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/light_yellow"/>
             <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/light_yellow"/>
             <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/light_yellow"/>
             <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/light_yellow"/>
             <item android:color="@color/white"/>

     </selector>
```

Comment: shouldnt the selector be placed in res/color ?

Comment: selector is in res/drawable @pskink....

Comment: shouldnt the selector be placed in res/color ?

Comment: You mean U should place the selector in res/color instead of res/drawable?

Comment: No it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

1.you can use setAlpha(0 to 255 value) to set in textview so it will highlight or set opacity in android textview.

```
Use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838757/how-to-set-opacity-alpha-for-view-in-android
```

(for opacity set in textview)

2.other option set blink of textview:

```
public static void blinkView(final TextView txtView) {

        Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        anim.setDuration(400); // You can manage the time of the blink with this
                                // parameter
        anim.setStartOffset(20);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        txtView.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

this function set to blink your textview .....

I hope its useful to you..

Comment: I don't want to blink the TextView.I want the TextView stay highlighted.

Comment: please use 1st option..its useful to you. @KousiK

Comment: The link is not opening @dipali

Answer (score 0):

The Selection class could be used to achieve your objective. See the official documentation of Selection class below:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Selection.html

Also, the below link could be useful:

[ClickableSpan TextView stays selected after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232643/clickablespan-textview-stays-selected-after-click)

Comment: I don't want the TextView to be selected.I want after clicking on the TextView the color will be changed.